# Cannot seem to remove whitespaces from input file?

Tags: python, replace, strip

I'm trying to figure out how to process an input file and print it out without any whitespace present in the output.

My current script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

kf = open ('keyword.txt', 'r')
sl = open ('syslog.txt', 'r')

for line in kf:
    line.replace('\n', "")
    line.strip()
    print line
```

The output of this however looks like this:

```
polkitd

anacron

acpid

rt-kit daemon

goa

AptDaemon

AptDaemon.PackageKit

AptDaemon.Worker

python
```

Does anyone know how to remove the lines of whitespace between each item?

Comment: Thank you, being from a C# background I didn't think about this, but this in fact was the problem.

Comment: shouldnt the code be `line = line.replace('\n', "")`, since the replace function returns  a new string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both `replace` and `strip` return new objects, not change the one you are currently working with so your code should be something like this

```
line = line.replace(...)
line = line.strip(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `repr(line)` instead of `print line` and see what you get. If there is a `'\n'`, try calling `line.strip('\n')`. Also, try putting a comma `,` after `print line` as such `print line,`.